# NextAuth and Prisma not working in netlify using NextJS 14

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

The website is working properly on development and production mode but on my local machine
But after deploying to netlify and when i am going to test it it doens't work

[As you can see here it showing error on console [and the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbuQD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp3QY.png)

I have tried to deploy to vercel but i have reached the free limit so i cannot to deploy it again to vercel

And netlify it seems to not working for nextauth and prisma

Answer (score 0):

Any additional errors in the logs or Netlify?
That would help much more to understand what's happening.

It might be a missing environment variable on Netlify for instance.